# How to add a total column in last row in R dataframe having value with %

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I have below-mentioned dataframe in R:

```
country    product          profit_perc
USA        100              15.2%
Canada     10               10.25%
Russia     50               19.72%
Japan      30               25.23%
```

Required dataframe:

```
country    product          profit_perc
USA        100              15.2%
Canada     10               10.25%
Russia     50               19.72%
Japan      30               25.23%
Total      190              70.4%
```

Comment: How is your dataframe storing "15.2%"? Is it storing 15.2 and then using a format function to provide the "%"?

Comment: @JohnGarland: No, I'm fetching these details from MySQL table which has value in this format.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(data.table)
d <- read.table(text = "
country    product          profit_perc
USA        100              15.2
Canada     10               10.25
Russia     50               19.72
Japan      30               25.23", header=T
)

d <- setDT(d)
vars <- c("product", "profit_perc")

d <- rbindlist(list(
  d,
  d[,  lapply(.SD, sum), .SDcols=vars ][,country := "Tot"]
), use.names = T)

   country product profit_perc
1:     USA     100       15.20
2:  Canada      10       10.25
3:  Russia      50       19.72
4:   Japan      30       25.23
5:     Tot     190       70.40
```

You can also pass the index of the columns directly:

```
d <- rbindlist(list(
  d,
  d[,  lapply(.SD, sum), .SDcols=c(2:3) ][,country := "Tot"]
), use.names = T)
```

Comment: When I'm passing the columns like `Vars<-c(2:6)` it is not working.

Comment: Getting error `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument`.

Comment: Why 2:6?, I only see 2 columns

Comment: for the example point of view, I have mentioned only two columns. Though, I have manually entered the column name but still getting the same error.

Comment: it very difficult to help if you dont show what you have tried. Note that in my code I used vars and not Vars. It can be either a vector of names, or a vector in column indices.